# Excel DNA function without parameters still shows one parameter in Excel function wizard

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, excel-dna

Consider function `MyFunc` without parameters:

```
[ExcelFunction(Name = "MyFunc", Description = "My func")]
public static object MyFunc()
{
    return "My-Func";
}
```

Although it has no parameters, when called from Excel using the function wizard there is one parameter listed:

[image]

Where is this parameter coming from?

Can it be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long-standing Excel bug. The extra argument box only goes away when you remove the function description completely.

See also: [Register Excel UDF without arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309312/register-excel-udf-without-arguments)